# How to split string by comma within parenthesis but not those on double quote

Tags: c#, regex

How can I capture all parameter on sample string using Regex? I tried to use (\@\w+|\w+) pattern on https://regex101.com/ but it returns all words on sample string which is not what I expect.

```
.selector(@background, height, font "font-family, font family", @width : 10px, "red");

expected output should capture 5 parameters:

 1. @background
 2. height
 3. font "font-family, font family"
 4. @width : 10px
 5. "red"
```

I'm having difficulties on combining regular expression and it took me an hour to figure it out that is why I decide to ask for a help.

Comment: What tools are you using ?

Comment: the code above was intended for c# Regex.Matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^.*?\(|,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|\).*$
```

You can split by this and remove `empty string` from the result.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nD5jY4/6

Comment: This is the most neatest among other answers! Thank you very much @vks

Answer (score 2):

First, I would extract the interesting part between the parenthesis, then I would read the internal parameters:

```
var args = str.match(/\(([^\)]+)\)/)[1].match(/[^,"]+("[^"]+")*/g)
```

Result:

[image]

The idea of the second part (`[^,"]+("[^"]+")*`) is to explicitly include parts between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a all-in-one regex:

```
/(?<=[,\(])(?:\s*)([^,"]*(?<dq>")?(?(dq)[^"]+"[^\(\),]*))(?:\s*)/g
```

Explanation:

- a parameter is something either after a comma or an opening bracket -> control this by a positive lookbehind `(?<=[,\(])`
- match but don't take any extra whitespace -> `(?:\s*)` outside the caputring group (nicer).
- In the capturing group:

  - begin by matching anything but comma and double quote.
  - if a double quote is encountered, match anything till another double quote is matched.

See on https://regex101.com/r/pC9fB6/1 the results.

**Note:** dystroy points out in a comment behind that lookbehind assertion is not supported by all regex engines (e.g. JavaScript). A possible solution is to put the character class `[,\(]` of the lookbehind assertion inside the non-capturing  group of whitespace: `(?:[,\(]\s*)`. The result is almost the same, the numbered captured matches are exactly the same.

Comment: Note that many tools/languages don't support lookbehind (for example JavaScript). As OP didn't precise the tool, I can't tell if it would be a problem here but it should be precised.

Comment: @dystroy You are absolutely right, but since the OP mentions the site regexp101.com, I assume he has access to all available features. To avoid the lookbehind syntax, you may put the content of it into the non-capturing group with the whitespaces: `(?:[,\(]\s*)`.

Comment: Since the OP doesn't mention any tool, I'm sure he doesn't know that it matters and that there are differences between engines.

Comment: @dystroy I edit my post to add a note about this fact.